# How to hide labels in ios-charts?

Tags: swift, ios-charts

I need disable some elements from my chart.

I used the [iOS-charts](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts) library in (Swift 2), however I can't understand how to disable the following:

1. Hide right and left numbers
2. Hide description color square
3. Hide all vertical lines

[image]

Comment: Look for `drawGridLines` and/or `DrawGridLines` or something alike in `XAxis` and `YAxis`. Get the `ChartLegend` of the Graph, and hide it. You should really look into the doc for Android, which is quite similar: https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki

Comment: @Larme Thank you. Find only how to find vertical lines. But still can't find how to hide numbers and color square....
In docs can't find anything about it...

Comment: Now I find it. In leftAxis.drawLabelsEnabled

Answer (score 112, accepted):

```
self.chartView.xAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = false
self.chartView.leftAxis.drawLabelsEnabled = false
self.chartView.legend.enabled = false
```

will do the job

Comment: self.chartView.legend.enabled = false work for me  for hiding legend .Great Thanks

Answer (score 4):

```
self.chartView.drawEntryLabelsEnabled = false
```

This will hide the label from `PieChart` and shows only value. Also shows legend with label texts.

Answer (score 0):

For only hide the top one:

```
graphCell.lineChartView.leftAxis.drawTopYLabelEntryEnabled = false
```